# Can someone tell me why my app crashes when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs

I added a weather component in my app that fetches weather from open weather map. It works fine until I refresh the page, then it breaks.

If I comment the weather component out when refreshing and then add it back in when loaded it renders and works.

I'm not sure what's causing this error.
Here's some images of the console after refreshing for reference.

It seems to be undefined when refreshed. What's causing this issue?

[image]

[image]

```js
// Weather component is called as normal in Home page 

 <div className="main-section-one">
          <Weather />
          <ToDoWidget />
        </div>
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

//CSS
import '../css/Weather.css'

function Weather() {

// API 
const URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=barcelona&appid=APIKEY';

// State 
const [weatherDetails, setWeatherDetails] = useState({});

async function getWeather() {
let fetchUrl = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=barcelona&appid=APIKEY&units=metric');
let data = await fetchUrl.json()

setWeatherDetails(data)
}

//Use Effect 
useEffect(() => { 
getWeather();
  
  
   }, [])

  return (

    <div className="weather-container">
        <div className="weather-one">
            <div className="city">
                <h3>Barcelona</h3>
                <h1 className='temp'>{weatherDetails.main.temp}°C</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="current-weather">
                <h3 className='current'>Sunny</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="weather-two">
            <div className="">
                <p>{weatherDetails.main.feels_like}°C</p>
                <p className='weather-details'>Feels Like</p>
            </div>
            <div className="">
                <p>{weatherDetails.main.humidity}%</p>
                <p className='weather-details'>Humidity</p>
            </div>
            <div className="">
                <p>{weatherDetails.wind.speed} MPH</p>
                <p className='weather-details'>Wind Speed</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default Weather
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` and `wind` properties may be `undefined`. Secure it.

```
<h1 className='temp'>{weatherDetails.main?.temp}°C</h1>
                                        ^^^ optional chaining

<p>{weatherDetails.wind?.speed} MPH</p>
```

Reference: **[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)**

Comment: That worked! I learned a lot from that, appreciate it!